# Render DesignAttribute configuration by visualforce page (LightningOut)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, lightning-out, design-attributes

Hi I have a lightning component with **design attributes**.
I want to render this component in salesforce classic view.
So I have created a visualforce page and embedded the lightning component using **Lightning:out**

Now Iam Not able to get the design attribute values when Iam tried to render the page in a object details page

Please anyone help me on this,Iam in urgent soltuion

Comment: I think you can set values to the attribute from the lightning out app directly, why would you want to access the design attribute?

Comment: I have to dynamically choose an fiedset in design attribute

Comment: Hi Gowtham, Welcome to SFSE!
Please take a [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how the community works and to get familiar with some rules to ask a good question. Adding _urgency_ to your question does not mean you would get a faster answer, so kindly refrain from doing so.

Comment: Now to answer your question, design attributes are only supported by lightning app builder, when you port a component to visualforce, you would lose that ability. You would need to hardcode/set the design parameters when setting up the component in a visualforce page.